# MooTools Plugins

Tags: javascript, mootools

Im looking for some good resources for MooTools.  jQuery has a nice plugins site.  Does anyone know of a similar site for mootools plugins?

Specifically Im looking for:

- Grid Component
- Modal Dialog Component
- Treeview

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clearly not looked very far (at least for the repository) - any google search for 'official mootols plugins' would have done the trick. Even a look at the mootools homepage reveals The Mootools Forge:

http://mootools.net/forge/

I cannot comment on the availability of the individual items yet I know treeview is available, modal dialogues also - that leaves the grid component.

**update**

If i *had* to pick, i'd go with http://www.jsfiddle.net/sixtyseconds/zNMQy/ for modal view (by 60 seconds, aka chris pitt) - consise, to the point and customisable BY YOU. events etc as you'd expect.

As for tree view, the only one I used a while back is called... mooTree, http://sites.google.com/a/mindplay.dk/mootree/Home - *very* flexible (adopt structure from html, xml or json source if memory serves etc).

Comment: Dimitar Thanks for the site but I have been there. and pickings are slim. Not many choices. I hope your not saying this is it. 2 modal dialog plugins to choose from and 2 tree views. And I cant seem to find a decent gridview. For the modals and TreeViews which have you used and what do you recommend?

Comment: please view revised answer. i tend to write my own stuff and not use plugins. keep in mind that the mootools forge is only a few months old and it is somewhat time consuming to package and up plugins to github to release (which is why I tend not to release any plugins there cept for mooSelecta which was just for testing). **gridview?** what is this meant to do?

Comment: Dimitar, thanks for your suggestions. What I mean by GridView is something similar to Jquery Plugin jqgrid.  I have seen a few from google search but nothing that really make me say "WOW".

Answer (score 1):

MooTools.net/Forge has lots of widgets and UI:

- For Grid Component, OmniGrid
- For Modal Dialog, MUX.Dialog
- For Treeview, Tree or Mif.Tree

You may also wish to check Mocha for Mootools, and JxLib for Mootools, both being UI frameworks.